# Как использовать actions и state из основного store в модулях

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как использовать actions и state из основного store в модулях
Нужно получить в файле backend.js доступ к state и actions из основного store

```
//store.js
import { createStore } from 'vuex'
import backend from '@/store/modules/backend'

const store = createStore({
state: () => ({})
actions: {}
modules: {
  backend
}
export default store

//backend.js
const  mutations = {
 HANDLE_CALL_BUTTON_CLICK(state) {
   const isError = Math.random() < 0.5 ? true : false 

   if (!state.isCallInProgress && !isError) {
     this.dispatch('startCall') 
   } else if (state.isCallInProgress) {
     this.dispatch('hangUp') 
   } else { 
     this.dispatch('showFailedCallModal') 
   } 
  }
}

const actions = {
  ...
}

export default {
 mutations,
 actions,
}
```

Comment: Нужны такие доступы где именно? В геттерах, мутациях или в действиях?

Comment: В мутациях
Ниже код, который я перенес из главного store в модуль
const mutations = {
  HANDLE_CALL_BUTTON_CLICK(state) {
    const isError = Math.random() < 0.5 ? true : false

    if (!state.isCallInProgress && !isError) {
      this.dispatch('startCall')
    } else if (state.isCallInProgress) {
      this.dispatch('hangUp')
    } else {
      this.dispatch('showFailedCallModal')
    }
  },
}

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, этот код в сам вопрос через кнопку [Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1378138/edit).

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите в модулях `vuex` использовать глобальное состояние и геттеры, `rootState` и `rootGetters` передаются 3-м и 4-м аргументами в функции геттеров, а также как свойства в объекте `context`, передаваемом в функции действий.

Для запуска действий или совершения мутаций в глобальном пространстве имён нужно добавить `{ root: true }` 3-м аргументом в `dispatch` и `commit`.

```
modules: {
  foo: {
    namespaced: true,

    getters: {
      // `getters` ограничены геттерами данного модуля
      // вы можете использовать rootGetters из 4-го аргумента геттеров
      someGetter (state, getters, rootState, rootGetters) {
        getters.someOtherGetter // -> 'foo/someOtherGetter'
        rootGetters.someOtherGetter // -> 'someOtherGetter'
        rootGetters['bar/someOtherGetter'] // -> 'bar/someOtherGetter'
      },
      someOtherGetter: state => { ... }
    },

    actions: {
      // dispatch и commit также ограничены данным модулем
      // они принимают опцию `root` для вызова в глобальном пространстве имён
      someAction ({ dispatch, commit, getters, rootGetters }) {
        getters.someGetter // -> 'foo/someGetter'
        rootGetters.someGetter // -> 'someGetter'
        rootGetters['bar/someGetter'] // -> 'bar/someGetter'

        dispatch('someOtherAction') // -> 'foo/someOtherAction'
        dispatch('someOtherAction', null, { root: true }) // -> 'someOtherAction'

        commit('someMutation') // -> 'foo/someMutation'
        commit('someMutation', null, { root: true }) // -> 'someMutation'
      },
      someOtherAction (ctx, payload) { ... }
    }
  }
}
```